# Php Image does not show, firs tphp image error second php doesn't call out

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

$id = $_GET["ident"];
$pat = '/^[0-9]+$/';
if(!preg_match($pat, $id)){
    exit; // broken image
}

// Using prepared statement, and bind-result don't work
// too well for a blob. PHP tries to allocate 16Mbye for the blob!
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','9876543210','student13');
$query = "select image from Picys where ident=$id";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

$err = $mysqli->error;
if(!empty($err)){
    exit;
}

$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
$bytes = $row[0];

echo $bytes;


?>
```

This is how i get my picture from my SQL server

but when i call this ImagefromMySQL.php it doesn't work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Display Picture</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>A Picture from Our Collection</h1>
    <?php 
    $id = $_GET["ident"];
    echo "<img src='./ImageFromMySQL.php?id=$id' />"
    ?>
    <hr />
    <h2>Tags</h2>
    <?php

    $stmt->close();
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select Tagstr from PicyTags where Picid=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($tag);
    $count = 0;
    while($stmt->fetch()){
        if($count==0){
            echo "<bold>Existing tags:</bold>";
        }
        $count++;
        echo "$tag<br />";
    }
    $mysqli->close();
    ?>
    <br />
    <h3>Add tag</h3>
    <p>You may add tags that characterize the contents of this picture.</p>
    <form action="./AddTag.php?ident=<?php echo $id ?>" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Your tag</legend>
                <input type="text" size="16" maxlength="16" />
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Tag" />
    </form>
</body>
```

My SQL database is just look like this
ident    title     comment     image
  6        sds       sdsds      BLOB - 80.5KiB
  1        aaa        sss       BLOB - 123.6KiB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your PHP code is doing: `$_GET["ident"];` but your HTML is doing: `?id=$id`.  You either need to change `$_GET['indent']` to `$_GET['id']` or change `?id=` to `?ident=`

Another way to debug problems is to open the image directly in the browser and it will show you the PHP errors that occurred instead of creating an image. You also may need to comment out the content-type header to see the errors.